# Dropdown inside a user control not firing the event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my user control markup below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="globalDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
```

Code:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    globalDropDown.SelectedIndexChanged += globalDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged;
    base.OnInit(e);
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.ConfigureDropDown();
    }
}

private void ConfigureDropDown()
{
    // databind happens here //
}

protected void globalDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // logic here //
}
```

When I changed the dropdown value, it hits the OnLoad not the method assigned to the event. What cause this issue?

*EDIT*
My control is being loaded on a placeholder.

Comment: Actually it should hit both, OnLoad first, then event handler, in that order. I assume that is not the case, right?

Comment: If your ddl is in a updatepanel it wont postback no matter what..

Comment: In your asp page on the DDL tag..OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"

Comment: @Andrei - yeah .. OnLoad only

Comment: @Jonny - no update panels.

Comment: Actually, Page_Init is only fired once, on the first load of the page. So you event subscription does not happen during the postback, and that might the reason why handler is not called. Try moving your subscription to the Page_Load (this one is called on every loading, including postbacks), or as Jonny suggested, to markup

Comment: Could you provide whole source code and page markup?